# How can I read the favorites contacts inside service?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am looking for a way to get the  contacts in the favorites list inside service from phone number or from name it dose not matter. Can any one help me with this?

It's not important to use any code related to this code

I found in the developer.android.com something like this (IN_VISIBLE_GROUP).
How to use this variable in my case?

```
   case (PICK_CONTACT):
              if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                      Uri contactData = data.getData();
                      Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                      ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                              String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                              String id =c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People._ID));
                              Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                      Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that you are searching a contact by name..
If you want to get Favourite value of all the possible contacts , drop the selection parameter in the given code.

//First get the contact ID from a display name as:-

```
String displayName = "Albert Einstein";

Uri contacts = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

cur = cr.query(contacts, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME +"="+displayName,null, null);

int contactIdIndex = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID);

int contactId = cur.getInt(contactIdIndex);

//Make a query to get the Starred value:-

Cursor starred = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED },
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + contactId,
null, null);

if (starred != null && starred.moveToFirst()) 
{
int fav = starred.getInt(0);
}

if (starred != null)
starred.close();            
}
```

You can drop the step of getting Contact ID and then querying for Starred value and directly query based on Display name

Comment: A 100000000000000000 thank you 
:)
can i do this for family group??
and if i can can you please tell me how
:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
final private static class DataQuery {
    public static final int COLUMN_MIMETYPE = 1;
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE = 2;
    public static final int COLUMN_RAWCONTACT_ID = 3; 
    public static final int COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER = COLUMN_DATA1;
    public static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Data._ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID };

    public static final String SELECTION_PHONE = Data.DATA1 + "=?";
}

long findContact(Context context, String number) {
    long rawContactId = -1;
    final Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI, DataQuery.PROJECTION, DataQuery.SELECTION_PHONE, new String[] { number }, null);
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            rawContactId = cursor.getLong(DataQuery.COLUMN_RAWCONTACT_ID);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return rawContactId;
}
```

Comment: thank you  for your responding but it dose not work

i have the phone number and the contact name and the contact id 
but i just want to know to check this person to witch group he belongs
:(

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's try with this...

```
    private static final Uri DATAGROUP_CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(Data.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).build();

public static void querytGroups(Context context) {
    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    long groupid=getGroupId(resolver, "Family");

    final Cursor c = resolver.query(DATAGROUP_CONTENT_URI, DataQueryForContactsInGroup.PROJECTION, DataQueryForContactsInGroup.SELECTION, new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, String.valueOf(groupid)}, null);

    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            final long rawContactId = c.getLong(DataQueryForContactsInGroup.RAW_CONTACT_ID);
            //do something
        } 
    }finally {
        c.close();
    }
}

private static long getGroupId(final ContentResolver resolver, String groupName) {
    long groupid = -1;
    Cursor cur = null;
    try {
        cur = resolver.query(Groups.CONTENT_URI, DataQueryForGroup.PROJECTION, DataQueryForGroup.SELECTION, new String[]{"%"+groupName+"%"}, null);         
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            return groupid= cur.getLong(DataQueryForGroup.GROUP_ID);
        } 
    }finally {
        if (cur!=null) cur.close();
    }
    return groupid;
}

private interface DataQueryForGroup {
    public final static String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {Groups._ID};
    public static final String SELECTION = Groups.TITLE+" LIKE ?";
    public final static int GROUP_ID = 0;
}

private interface DataQueryForContactsInGroup {
    public final static String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID };
    public static final String SELECTION = "("+Data.MIMETYPE + "=?) and ("+ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID+ "=?)";
    public final static int RAW_CONTACT_ID = 0;
}
```

Please consider that if your google account is not English you need to look for the proper group's name

Comment: 1000000000000000000000000000000000 Thank you :) you are awesome man :)